# Checking for words in a string in a list of strings efficiently

Tags: python, algorithm, list-comprehension

I have a long string, let us say `astr = "I am a very long string and I could contain a lot of text, so think of efficiency here"`. I also have a list `alist = ["I", "am a", "list", "of strings", "and each string", "could be made up of many words", "so think of efficiency here"]`. Now, my list of strings also has a corresponding list of integers `alist_ofints = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` that represents how many *points* each string in this list equals.

I am supposed to create a function that finds how many of the words in `astr` appear the list `alist`, and create a "points" counter using the corresponding points list `alist_ofints`. So, in this example, the words "I", "am a", "so think of efficiency here" appear twice, once, and once respectively. That would give us `1*2 + 2*1 + 7*1 = 11` points.

I have come up with two naive solutions. The first is to create a function that looks into this list of strings `alist` and checks to see if each item is in `astr`, and if it is, to apply the obvious following logic. This is inefficient because I will be looking into `astr` a `len(alist)` amount of times. That is a waste, isn't it? It is clean and to the point, but inefficient.

The second solution was to make `astr` a list of words, and I would check each word at index `i` through to index `j`, where `i` is where I am in the list and `j` is the length of the phrase in `alist` that I am looking for. So, "am a" is a phrase of length 2 (since it has two words in it), so I would look at i = some number, and j = some number + 1. If I am looking for the phrase `"and each string"`, i = some number, j = some number + 3. So I am looking  at three words, when testing for this phrase. Now, I think this also has the same time complexity. Although I am not looping through the `astr` list once, I am looping through my list of words `alist` `len(list(astr))` times. Also, I have to create a list of `astr`, which adds some complexity, I imagine.

So, I like the first solution better so far, because its the easiest, simplest, and cleanest. Is there a better way to do this? Extra points if you can find a list comprehension way...

Thank you

NOTE: I know `list(astr)` will not return the list of words. Imagine that for this example, it does.

TLDR: I have two lists. I need to check if each element in a list is equal to an element in the other list and create a count of how many times they appear. Is there a more efficient way of doing this than to check every element in list 1 against every other element in list 2 (I think this is O(n^2))?

Comment: You should post your "naive" solutions.

Comment: Please keep it short and minimal, this is rather verbose

Comment: @asongtoruin I make a habit of not coding anything before I have a clear algorithm set out that I want to implement

Comment: @Chris_Rands feel free to just read the first three paragraphs... I am trying to give the community as much info as possible into my thought process. It isn't important if you don't think it is relevant to how you would come up with your solution

Comment: You have "algorithms" you want to implement. I think it would be far easier to understand what you're doing via code rather than a wall of text.

Comment: Any assumptions on the alist? Are the entries unique, can the strings overlap? such as alist=["I", "I am", ..]. How are the points computed in these cases?

Comment: Try and implement both of the algorithms, I have a feeling you'll see how your second solution can be either marginally faster or quite slower then your first one. Performance will not only depend on the length of the string, but also on the amount of elements in alist AND the length of each.

Comment: @SaiBot you can assume the entries will be unique. "I" and "I am" are treated as two different objects. Good question though. I suppose "I" and "I am" will count as a point towards "i" and "I am".

Comment: By sorting the alist first and then performing binary search, you should be able to get the runtime complexity down.

Comment: @SaiBot  What will I be searching for in alist?

Comment: will the list of word have input like ['ab', 'bc', 'ab bc'] ans input string = "ab bc" and points array as [5, 8, 2]. in which case picking the individually occouring words will give more points that the whole word

Comment: Thank you for describing in words rather than code how you're thinking about this. I think that's great.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Hello my friend, you have helped me many times in the past. Glad to see you here. And thank you, I think that is the best way too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient algorithm could index the long string astr using a string index (e.g., [Suffix Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array)). Then you search each entry in alist in the index and increment the points accordingly when you found results.

The runtime for indexing astr is then O(n) where n is the length of astr.

Searching an entry from alist of length m in the index is in O(log n)

Overall you should get away with O(p log n) where p is the number of entries in alist.

**Example**

Lets consider the long string `astr` to be

> I am a very long string

then the corresponding suffix array (all lower-case) will be

> SA = [1 4 6 11 16 5 2 8 22 15 0 20 12 3 21 14 13 19 9 17 18 7 10]

these are all suffixes of astr (represented by their starting index) sorted lexicographical. For example `SA[9] = 15` represents the string in `astr` starting at position 15 ("g string").

Now lets assume your list of phrases

> alist = ["I am", "very long",...]

then for each of the entries you want to search the occurrences in the suffix array. This is done using binary search on the suffix array. For "I am" this will look as follows:

First you look at the middle entry of the suffix array (SA[11] = 20). Then you look at the suffix represented by that index ("ing"). Since this suffix is larger than your search phrase "I am" you want to look in the left half of your suffix array. Continue this binary search until you have found the phrase or you are sure it's not in there.

Comment: This is a very intriguing answer. Could you give me an example of how this works? So, I have my suffix aray representing my `astr`. How do I search for each word in `alist` in my suffix array?

Comment: This is probably the most efficient way, but if you want the search in O(log n) , you need to add the time to actually sort the list you have.

Comment: @ChatterOne could you explain how I would use the suffix array to search for items in my alist in the suffix array?

Comment: @ChatterOne this is true if you use comparison based sorting. For suffix arrays you can do better since you know which symbols are used. So sorting is actually in O(n) (see construction of suffix arrays)

Comment: @SaiBot So, a count sort? It looks like you can store the count immediately then, right?

Comment: @SaiBot After a lot of consideration, I found this to be the coolest answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have written this line that [seems to do exactly what you want](https://trinket.io/python/a3e118682a):

```
print sum([str.count(s) * i for (s,i) in zip(alist, alist_ofints)])
```

It is more like your first approach, but I don't find it that inefficient.

One thing you should note though is that `str.count(s)` only finds the numver of [non-overlapping occurrences](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) of `s` in `str`.

Comment: This looks good, but as you mentioned, this is exactly how I would have done my first approach. Is there no other more efficient way?

Comment: can you tell us why efficiency is so important in your case. Is your list is size a million? @JohnLexus

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Yes, quite literally. Maybe even more. Doing neural net stuff and working with extremely large data

Comment: @JohnLexus I don't think there is a much more efficient way to compute this. I'm not sure how `str.count()` is implemented under the cover, but you might try replacing it with an implementation of the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm.

Comment: @JohnLexus Beware though; KMP will also return overlapping matches (i.e. `"abab"` will be found inside `"ababab"`) 2 times.

Comment: @JohnLexus One thing you need to understand is that how performance is measured. You are saying you are working with NN stuffs so your single string size may vary your list size will vary your machine's power, RAM etc. So a lot too variable to measure performance. I suggest implement your alogs and measure performance using time command or some profiler and if performance is significantly slow then you can ask. I don't seen in any of your solutions that performance is coming as low. One more suggestion try first and then ask what is the solution.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki you are absolutely correct; this is not the complete problem, it is just a very similar problem to the one I am facing. The real problem I am facing is too dense and difficult for me to explain - this is a much more easy to understand problem... but thank you for your input

Comment: Instead of stackoverflow, ask this on codereview.stackexchange.com. Take this question with your two implementations and ask that is there any better solution? Because technically you have a working solution and you are not getting any error so it shouldn't be on stackoverflow

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Aha! I see, you are definitely correct. Thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 1):

You can build a [Trie](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/) data structure for the list of words with the end nodes containing the index of the points array.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)A trie structure for the input = `["A","to", "tea", "ted", "ten", "i", "in", and "inn"]` would look like this

```html
<p><a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Trie_example.svg#/media/File:Trie_example.svg"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Trie_example.svg" alt="Trie example.svg" height="145" width="155"></a><br>By <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Booyabazooka" class="extiw" title="en:User:Booyabazooka">Booyabazooka</a> (based on PNG image by <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Deco" class="extiw" title="en:User:Deco">Deco</a>). Modifications by <a href="//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Superm401" class="mw-redirect" title="User:Superm401">Superm401</a>. - own work (based on PNG image by <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Deco" class="extiw" title="en:User:Deco">Deco</a>), Public Domain, <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=1197221">Link</a></p>
```

So we can run through the entire length of the input string and every time we encounter a end of word node add it's points and move on.

So the search for the entire word can be done in linear time.

But in case of overlapping list items like `["ab", "cd", "abcd"]`, with points `[3, 4, 1]` and the word was `abcd`. The we will not be able to have a linear time solution after pre-processing because after every time we encounter a end of word the max points can come from either.

1. Extending the string so far word and looking further ahead.
2. Starting to look for remaining string as an individual word from the list.

Time and space complexity to build the Trie structure : `O(w * m)` where `w` is the amount of words and `m` is the max size of the word in the list.

Search can be done in `O(m)` where `m` is the length of the word being searched for.

Comment: You should add more context or some kind of example that why trie could be useful in OP's case. It's not very clear currently that why OP should use trie data structure

Comment: If this is true, I think its also a good solution, I will have to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

(I think this is similar to thebenman's answer.) Depending on the kinds of overlaps in `alist`, you might get away with turning `alist` into a dictionary (or a nested dictionary, i.e., a tree):

```
{
  I: [(None, 1)],
  am: [(a, 2)],
  list: [(None, 3)],
  of: [(strings,4)],
  and: [(each, 0), (string, 5)],
  could: [(be, 0), (made, 0)...,(words, 6)],
  so: [(think, 0), (of, 0)...,(here, 7)]
}
```

Now we could traverse `astr` once *as words* without indexing it, keeping a reference to and updating all currently open, accumulating matches.

Answer (score 1):

You could also generate all possible subsequences, use a `Counter` on it and then the lookup time would be almost O(1).

This would take more memory to generate the dictionary (or index), but it would be more efficient in case you need to lookup the same long string multiple times.

Something like this:

```
from collections import Counter


def get_all_counts(input_string):
    cnt = Counter()
    length = len(input_string)
    alist = []
    s = input_string.split()
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        current_subsequence = ''
        for j in range(i, len(s)):
            current_subsequence += ' ' + s[j]
            cnt[current_subsequence.strip()] += 1 # I've put 1 here, but you could easily replace it with a lookup of your "points"
    return cnt


counts = get_all_counts(
    'I am a very long string and I could contain a lot of text, so think of efficiency here')

print(counts['am'])
print(counts['of'])
```

Probably using `itertools` would be better, but you should get the idea.

Another advantage of this is that you could turn this into a pandas dataframe and do queries on it.

For example something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(counts, orient='index').reset_index()

print(df[df[0] > 1])
```

would give you all the substrings with an occurrence greater than 1.